# Why does the OpenCV Mat object not contain the expected values after I assigned them in a nested for loop?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I am having trouble understanding how the `Mat` type in `OpenCV` works, and why it behaves the way it behaves in the following situation. Unfortunately, the [docs](http://www.prism.gatech.edu/~ahuaman3/docs/OpenCV_Docs/tutorials/basic_0/basic_0.html) that I have considered for this example don't help me much here...

Here is my program:

```
Mat matrix (5, 5, CV_16S);
matrix.setTo(0);

printf("matrix %d, %d: \n", matrix.cols, matrix.rows);
for( size_t i = 0; i < matrix.cols; i++ ) {
    for( size_t j = 0; j < matrix.rows; j++ ) {
        matrix.at<int>(i,j) = 200;
        printf( " %d ", matrix.at<int>(i,j));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
cout << "matrix: " << matrix << endl;
```

The first output that is generated within the nested `for`-loop gives me the results that I would expect, which is:

matrix 5, 5: 
 200  200  200  200  200 
 200  200  200  200  200 
 200  200  200  200  200 
 200  200  200  200  200 
 200  200  200  200  200

This is because I created a `Mat` object with 5 rows and columns and assigned value 200 to each entry when looping over them.

However, the last line, where I use `cout` to print the `Mat`, gives me the following output:

```
matrix: [200, 0, 200, 0, 200;
  200, 0, 200, 0, 200;
  200, 0, 200, 0, 200;
  200, 0, 200, 0, 200;
  200, 0, 200, 0, 200]
```

Here, only every second entry is assigned to the value 200, unlike I would have expected. Can someone explain to me the logic behind this? What am I missing, what's causing the `0` entries, when before I have assigned each value in the matrix with `200`?

Comment: It could be related to the fact the matrix stores 16 bit signed numbers. Does it make a difference it you initialize it with, say, `CV_32S`?

Comment: oh wow, it does!! I played around with the types before and always recevied somewhat strange results, but I wasn't able to draw the important relations... so, initializing it with `Mat matrix (5, 5, CV_32S);` actually makes the output as expected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're doing 2 things wrong there,

1) if your Mat is CV_16S, you have to access it as `m.at<short>(r,c);`
(in other  words, you `at<type>()` has to *exactly* match the Mat's type.)

2) it's row/col world in opencv, so if i goes over cols and j over rows, that must be: `m.at<short>(j,i);`

Comment: Annoyingly, `short` can be more than 16 bits. I'd try `int16_t`.